# Why would EF Core DbSet LINQ not find a value that exists?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have a program that seems to be skipping/ignoring isolated records? I'm added 60k records and two records are generating a fun error that has me scratching my head.

The error is that my DbSet can't seem to find a record using LINQ but manually in the Immediate Window I can see that the record matches?

```
DbSet<Party> SetParty = cntx.Set<Party>();
party = SetParty.Where(x => x.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
```

after the above lines of code the party object is 'null' but when I break right after the second line and run tests in the Immediate Window I get the following.

```
?new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<User_Portal_Web_Application.Models.dbo.Party>(cntx.Parties).Items[4].Name == name
true
?party
null
?SetParty
{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[User_Portal_Web_Application.Models.dbo.Party]}
    EntityType: {EntityType: Party}
    Local: {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.LocalView<User_Portal_Web_Application.Models.dbo.Party>}
```

What could be causing this record to be skipped or wrongly compared in the LINQ? I think it might be a special character (ie. non line breaking space) but why would the Immediate window not act the same way?

Comment: One is evaluated client side (C#), the other - server side (SQL, database). This especially with strings can produce differences.

Comment: Would you happen to have a link where I could go and read up on this? I'm curious if this has not been a thorn in my side for another issue I have as well.

Comment: Here is some data about EF and `strings`: [Collations and Case Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity). You should look at the SQL generated from your LINQ and debug the SQL query to figure out the issue. LINQPad can be helpful.